# Virtual member functions in most-derived class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Consider the following base class:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base(void);
    virtual void foo(void);
    virtual void bar(void) = 0;
}
```

Now suppose I know that a given class should be the most derived class of Base. Should I declare the functions virtual? The most derived class can/will be used polymorphically with Base.

For example, should I use `MostDerived1` or `MostDerived2`?

```
class MostDerived1 : public Base
{
public:
    ~MostDerived1(void);
    void foo(void);
    void bar(void);
}

class MostDerived2 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~MostDerived2(void);
    virtual void foo(void);
    virtual void bar(void);
}
```

I'm leaning towards MostDerived1 because it most closely models the intent of the programmer: I **don't** want another child class of MostDerived1 to be used polymorphically with MostDerived1.

Is this reasoning correct? Are there any good reasons why I should pick MostDerived2, aside from the obvious `there could be a >0% chance MostDerived2 should be used polymorphically with any deriving classes (class OriginalAssumptionWrong : public MostDerived2)`?

Keep in mind `MostDerived1`/`MostDerived2` can both be used polymorphically with `Base`.

Comment: What is the difference between `MostDerived1` and 2? The dtor and the functions of these classes are implicitly `virtual` (because their base class declares them as `virtual`). Note C++11 has `override` and `final`.

Comment: hmm, I see. I didn't know virtual meant virtual forever. So at best it's just poorly done documentation?

Comment: It clearly expresses that this function participates in a dynamic dispatch. That does not document (imply) that it *overrides* a base class function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't *turn off* `virtual`ness. Another class derived from either `MostDerived1` or `MostDerived2` can also override any of the `virtual` functions regardless of whether you omit the `virtual` keyword somewhere in the class hierarchy or not.

If you want to enforce that no other class derives from `MostDerived1`, define it as

```
class MostDerived1 final : public Base
{
  // ...
};
```

The [`final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) keyword can also be used for individual `virtual` member functions, ensuring no derived class overrides that specific function.

Comment: You can't *turn off `virtual`ness*, but you can hide the base class function (accidentally) with a function having a very similar signature (like, adding a `const`) ;)

Comment: @DyP: And ensure that someone using the class in a common place where you rely on it is COMPLETELY baffled as to why it's calling a different function than the one in the class you expected!

Comment: @DyP Yep, but `override` does make it easy to avoid that gotcha these days

Comment: I think a fine example would be the combination of all three: `virtual void foo() final override;`

Answer (score 3):

Adding virtual to derived classes doesn't change their behavior, `MostDerived` and `MostDerived2` are have exactly the same behavior.

It does however document your intention, however.  I would recommend it for that purpose.  The `override` keyword also helps with this, assuming its available on your platform.

Answer (score 1):

Once function declear somewhere at the hierarchy as a virtual, it's virtual for ever.
You can use `final` or `override` if you using *C++11*

Comment: Even `final` doesn't change the virtuality of a function, i.e. you can't "restart" the hierarchy further down. You just get a compiler error.